# debugger automaticly disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, debugging

After I updated visual studio when I'm trying to debug my javascript code but debugger gets disconnected automatically.

I added a `console.log("......")` statement to the snippet:

[image]

The `console.log` statement is displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

The log show you:

> 1. Debugger attached
> 2. Shows the console.log("......")
> 3. Waiting for the debugger to disconnect

Let's talk about the last item, it shows that the debugger is still **running** and **listening** for the quiet command (usually `ctrl+c`).

So the debugger is up and running until disconnecting or quitting, so use it without any problem.

Comment: but when I want to take input from user it won't work as the debugger automatically close.

Comment: where is *"debugger automatically close"* ? I can't find it, the terminal shows you that the debugger is connected. @k211beg

Comment: https://youtu.be/chZXKayMBiY

Comment: Okay, I saw the video and realize that your program exited after a start, would you please add the related code snippet? is there any error in your code? @k211beg